# Combine multiple rows into one by coalescing one column's value as CSV from two tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'll divide this into three parts:

What I have:

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`.

**Table1**

| ObjectName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A | Active |
| C | Active |

**Table2**

| ParentObjectType | ChildObjectType |
| --- | --- |
| X | A |
| Y | C |
| Z | A |
| M | C |

What I want:

I want to write a stored procedure that gives a result that looks something like this:

| ObjectName | Status | ParentObjectName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Active | X, Z |
| C | Active | Y, M |

What I have tried: I tried using the `STUFF` function and I'm getting a weird result.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
    ObjectName,
    Status,
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + table2.ParentObjectType 
           FROM table1 
           INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.[ObjectName] = table2.[ChildObjectType]
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [ParentObjectName]
FROM 
    table1
```

**Output**

| ObjectName | Status | ParentObjectName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Active | X, Z, Y, M |
| C | Active | X, Z, Y, M |

Any help here is highly appreciated as I'm light handed on SQL and this is driving me nuts!

Comment: Tip: You might find it rather easier to use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of Ye Olde `FOR XML` approach.

Comment: @HABO Will do Kind Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O4mvvB68)

You are missing `WHERE` condition in your Subquery for a parent table.

Also I assume this is a typo. In Table2 you have column `ChildObjectType` but in your link you are linking over ˛`table2.[ChildObjectName]`

```
SELECT 
    ObjectName,
    Status,
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + table2.ParentObjectType 
           FROM table1 
           INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.[ObjectName] = table2.[ChildObjectName]
           WHERE Table1.ObjectName = src.ObjectName
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [ParentObjectName]
FROM 
    table1 src
```

Note: You can use STRING_AGG starting from [SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Apologies for the typo in the question and yes. Your solution works!

Comment: @Abhid glad, I've helped. Please consider what HABO mentioned. It's way better to use string_agg than STUFF. Also noting that marking answer as solution would help others and poster ;)

Comment: Will do! And I'm looking into improving the solution using STRING_AGG

Answer (score 0):

This helped me realize I didn't have this saved in my snippets, thanks! Being careful that`FOR XML PATH` will return XML Encoded text, so "&" becomes "&", see below for an example that shows you can add `, TYPE` to your `FOR XML` statement; This returns an xml datatype, that you can query the text out of with `value('.',...`.

I personally tend to favor subqueries below the `FROM`, so this also shows an alternative style for joining the data, via a `WHERE` clause inside the `APPLY` refernce:

```
DECLARE @tt1 TABLE ( ObjectName VARCHAR(10), StatusValue VARCHAR(20) )
INSERT INTO @tt1 
          SELECT 'A','Active'
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','Active'
UNION ALL SELECT 'D&E','Active'


DECLARE @tt2 TABLE (  A VARCHAR(100), B VARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'X','A'
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'Y','C'
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'Z','A'
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'M','C'
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'E&F','D&E' --sample "&" that should NOT render "&amp;"
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT '"G"','D&E'
INSERT INTO @tt2 SELECT 'F>G','C' --sample ">" that should NOT render "&gt;"


SELECT 
tt1.*,
f1.*
FROM
(SELECT ObjectName,StatusValue FROM @tt1) tt1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT 
    COALESCE(STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + CAST(tt2.A AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM
    @tt2 tt2 WHERE tt2.B = tt1.ObjectName FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1,1,''),'') [csv1] ) f1
```

I'm assuming that you are on a SQL server version that does not have string aggregating functions?